# Split individual strings in a list Python

Tags: python, string, split

How do I split individual strings in a list?

```
data = ('Esperanza Ice Cream', 'Gregory Johnson', 'Brandies bar and grill')
```

Return:

```
print(data)
('Esperanza', 'Ice', 'Cream', 'Gregory', 'Johnson', 'Brandies', 'bar', 'and', 'grill')
```

Comment: and your attempts are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach, using `join` and `split`:

```
items = ' '.join(data)
terms = items.split(' ')
print(terms)

['Esperanza', 'Ice', 'Cream', 'Gregory', 'Johnson', 'Brandies', 'bar', 'and', 'grill']
```

The idea here is to generate a single string containing all space-separated terms.  Then, all we need is a single call to the non regex version of `split` to get the output.

Comment: I like this approach. Do you foresee any problems coming from it, i.e. it solves the problem as stated, but maybe doesn't generalize as well as some other approach?

Comment: @ToddBurus It might not be the most space efficient method, because it generates a big ugly string.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ('Esperanza Ice Cream', 'Gregory Johnson', 'Brandies bar and grill')
data = [i.split(' ') for i in data]
data=sum(data, [])
print(tuple(data))
#('Esperanza', 'Ice', 'Cream', 'Gregory', 'Johnson', 'Brandies', 'bar', 'and', 'grill')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) for that like:

#### Code:

```
it.chain.from_iterable(i.split() for i in data)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import itertools as it

data = ('Esperanza Ice Cream', 'Gregory Johnson', 'Brandies bar and grill')
print(list(it.chain.from_iterable(i.split() for i in data)))
```

#### Results:

```
['Esperanza', 'Ice', 'Cream', 'Gregory', 'Johnson', 'Brandies', 'bar', 'and', 'grill']
```